# g++ compilation fails when profiling enabled

Tags: g++, gprof

I have a working program, which I want to profile. Thus, I just added a -pg switch to the Makefile. This gives thousands of repetitions of this same message:

```
/tmp/ccOlI4CC.s:62095: Error: bad expression
/tmp/ccOlI4CC.s:62095: Error: junk `mcount@GOTPCREL(%rip)' after expression
/tmp/ccOlI4CC.s:62417: Error: bad expression
/tmp/ccOlI4CC.s:62417: Error: junk `mcount@GOTPCREL(%rip)' after expression
```

I'm in the blue. What can I do about this?

Comment: Give some [mre] and details about your operating system. Give also a source code of your program, the compilation command, the exact version of `g++` and of `gprof`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by removing the -masm=intel flag.